# I need to access vectors in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

THis is my JSTL code.can u help me to correct this code.

```
<c:set var="answer" value="${N}"/> 
<c:set var="level" value="${Firm Level}"/> 
    <c:if test="${not empty objBrokerVO}"> 
        <c:forEach var="objAccessVO" items="${AccessVO}">
            <TR>
        <TD WIDTH="200"><c:out value="${objAccessVO.SiteDesc}"/></TD>
            <c:if test="${objAccessVO.getAccess=='F'}">
                <c:out var="answer" value="${Y}"/>
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${objAccessVO.getAccess=='G'}">
                            <c:out var="answer" value="${Y}"/>
                            <c:out var="level" value="${Granted User Level}"/>
                         </c:when>
                         <c:when test="${objAccessVO.getAccess=='N'}">
                             <c:out var="answer" value="${N}"/>
                         </c:when>
                         <c:when test="${objAccessVO.getAccess=='R'}">
                            <c:out var="answer" value="${N}"/>
                            <c:out var="level" value="${Revoked User Level}"/>
                        </c:when>
                    </c:choose>
           </c:if>      
      <TD ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="75"><B><c:out value="${answer}"/></B></TD>
      <TD ALIGN="CENTER" WIDTH="150"><B><c:out value="${level}"/></B></TD>
    </TR>
       </c:foreach>
    </c:if>
</TABLE>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Please make proper question. you need to show us the code(if any) along with problem description

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate through the Vector using JSTL here you go..

```
<c:forEach var="person" items="personVector">
             <c:out value="${person.name}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I have answered you how to iterate the `Vector` , now what is your question I am confused

Comment: I hav converted scriptlet to JSTL.check on my JSTL i'm not getting it correctly.

Comment: `check on my JSTL` where is yours ?